# Pyspark replace string in every column name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am converting Pandas commands into Spark ones. I bumped into wanting to convert this line into Apache Spark code:

This line replaces every two spaces into one.

```py
df = df.columns.str.replace('  ', ' ')
```

Is it possible to replace a string from all columns using Spark?
I came into this, but it is not quite right.

```py
df = df.withColumnRenamed('--', '-')
```

To be clear I want this

```
//+---+----------------------+-----+
//|id |address__test         |state|
//+---+----------------------+-----+
```

to this

```
//+---+----------------------+-----+
//|id |address_test          |state|
//+---+----------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `replace` method on all columns by iterating over them and then selecting, like so:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3)], "id: int, address__test: int, state: int")
df.show()
+---+-------------+-----+
| id|address__test|state|
+---+-------------+-----+
|  1|            2|    3|
+---+-------------+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

new_cols = [col(c).alias(c.replace("__", "_")) for c in df.columns]
df.select(*new_cols).show()
+---+------------+-----+
| id|address_test|state|
+---+------------+-----+
|  1|           2|    3|
+---+------------+-----+
```

On the sidenote: calling `withColumnRenamed` makes Spark create a Projection for each distinct call, while a `select` makes just single Projection, hence for large number of columns, `select` will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion.

We get all the target columns:

```py
columns_to_edit = [col for col in df.columns if "__" in col]
```

Then we use a for loop to edit them all one by one:

```py
for column in columns_to_edit:
    new_column = column.replace("__", "_")
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, new_column)
```

Would this solve your issue?